# Android MediaController seekbar chapter markers?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

I am currently working on a simple video player on Android OS 2.3.3 where I am using a `VideoView` to display a movie and using the `MediaController` to control the video.

I want to add a few chapter markers along the seekbar and was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use horizontal `SeekBar` instead of `MediaController`.

Put it in `RelativeLayout` and behind SeekBar set some views which will be chapter markers. This markers will be visible if they will be little bit bigger than SeekBar height. You can add this View's programmatically when needed by calculating their positions depend on video duration and seekbar length.

Of course layout can be little bit more complicated.

[image]